# What Datatype is created?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What data type does "two_days_in_a_row" create in Python? Does it create a list or a tuple, or any other datatype

In my Advanced Data Science with Python on Coursera Course 1, Week 4, Distributions lecture, prof said that two_days_in_a_row = 0 will create a list. I am still figuring why will be the case, why a list will be created. Help me know the answer. Thanks in advance!!!

```py
two_days_in_a_row = 0 
#creates a list
```

Comment: You must have misunderstood him. `type(two_days_in_a_row)` will be an integer. It's just a number. There's no list involved here. `two_days_in_a_row = []` would create a list.

Comment: A list will not be created. Either the lecturer is wrong, or you misunderstood them. `two_days_in_a_row = 0` assigns an `int` object to the variable `two_days_in_a_row`

Comment: I must remember not to take any courses on Coursera then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned a integer value to that variable.

Using `type()` will tell you what data type you have.

I.E: `type(two_days_in_a_row)` --> returns int

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse, Check below data types in python

```
two_days_in_a_row = 0
type(two_days_in_a_row): int

two_days_in_a_row = []
type(two_days_in_a_row): list

two_days_in_a_row = None
type(two_days_in_a_row): NoneType

two_days_in_a_row = ""
type(two_days_in_a_row): str

two_days_in_a_row = {}
type(two_days_in_a_row): dict

two_days_in_a_row = ()
type(two_days_in_a_row): tuple

two_days_in_a_row = 0.0
type(two_days_in_a_row): float

two_days_in_a_row = 2+3j
type(two_days_in_a_row): complex

two_days_in_a_row = True
type(two_days_in_a_row): bool
```

Comment: You could even do that in one line: `for x in (0, [], None, "", {}, (), 0.0, 2+3j, True): print(f'Type of {repr(x)} is {type(x)}.')` ;-)

Comment: You could, but it wouldn't make for a very good example if someone barely understands how python works :P

Comment: @Peter, haha, true. I would have included the output of above command line if formatting was supported in comments, because it prints effectively the same as this answer. I just wanted to add it as an example for anyone interested in it. I think it actually is quite Pythonic :-)